# Using 'would have had'

Tags: modal-verbs

I want to tell that 'If the question **would not have had** that statement then your answer is correct'.

Is the usage of **would not have had** correct here ? How do I frame the sentence?

Comment: Can the downvoter tell me the reason for downvote? This is my first question here. So it would be better if you can tell me how can I improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not use *will/would* in the protasis (the “if” part) of a conditional except for those rare occasions in which the modal actually means *to be willing to*. For example, these are perfectly grammatical:

- If you **will please be** seated, we **can** get started.
- If only you **would close** your eyes, you **could** see the invisible.

For your case, you need nothing more than the good old past perfect construction:

- If the question **had not had** that spurious bit, it **would have been** correct.

See also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085).

Answer (score 0):

So first up - in your first sentence - you most probably want to say/write: "I want to **say** that 'If the question would not have had that statement then your answer is correct'." A small correction...

To your question:
Yes - it's basically correct depending on the usage. The tense is potentially not right for the second half of the sentence, assuming the first half - it should read: 'If the question would not have had that statement then your answer **would have been** correct'.

The explanation:
An example where the phrase would be applicable is for an exam paper. The exam is in the past and a particular question may / may not have had an applicable statement. Then one's answer to the question, dependent on the statement, is right or wrong; in the past and a possibility...

Alternative:
If discussing something in the present terms then the sentence becomes: 'If the question didn't have that statement then your answer is correct'.

Comment: "Would not have had" could be correct in some cases, but the sentence in question is not one. I'd say "had not had" (with your additional correction from "is" -> "would have been") is the correct phrasing.